# How can I loop over an on on beforehand unknown loop size?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a large dataframe with chapter numbers, titles and subtitles and text all in strings. I want to filter out specific pieces of text between titles and subtitles chronologically, however the chapters do not have a constant number of subtitles. Therefore I do not know the bounds of the loop.

I am able to find the indices of all the titles and subtitles and locate and extract the specific text that I need, however I can only do this when I manually enter each subtitle string.

```
import pandas as pd

# Example of the contents of the file
series = (["1.1.1.1", "lots of useless text", "more useless text", "I want this text", "1.1.1.2","I want this text","Not this text","1.1.1.3","1.1.2.1","some lines of text","1.2.1.1","Interesting text","1.2.1.2" ])

# These two operations are to get the same structure as I have in my imported file
df2 = pd.DataFrame(series)
df2 = df2.iloc[:,0]

# Start of finding the first chapter
title = 1
subtitle = 1

# Change to string to find the location of the string
string_title = "1."+ str(title)+"."+str(subtitle)
process_loc = df2[df2.str.contains(string_title, na=False)]
idx = process_loc.index

#Locate text I want
true_text   = df2.str[0] == "I"
# Locate text for the subtitle.
text_range  = df2.loc[idx[0]:idx[2]]
text_list   = text_range[true_text == True]

#Loop over all subtitles to get all the subtitles and text I want in 1 DataFrame
new_df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Ordered'])
new_df2 = new_df2.append(process_loc.to_frame())
new_df2 = new_df2.append(text_list.to_frame())
```

I want to have the output:

- 1.1.1
- I want this text
- 1.1.1.2
- I want this text
- 1.1.1.3
- 1.1.2.1
- 1.2.1.1
- Interesting text
- 1.2.1.2

Is it possible to loop this or do I have to manually find all the subtitle numbers?

Comment: Have you tried using regex? If you know what you want you could use the pandas loc function and regex to collect what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to find rows matching your criteria, e.g. find all rows starting with `I` or with a number followed by a dot:

```
df2[df2.str.match('^I.*|^\d\..*')]
```

Output:

```
0              1.1.1.1
3     I want this text
4              1.1.1.2
5     I want this text
7              1.1.1.3
8              1.1.2.1
10             1.2.1.1
11    Interesting text
12             1.2.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks! Knowing this would have saved me a couple of hours to begin with.